# AWS S3 CloudFront - redirect from https://www.domain.com to https://domain.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Here is my AWS Route 53 Setup:
[image]

The domain https://www.migranthire.com doesn't work. How can i redirect from this domain to https://migranthire.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `www` site is pointing directly to an S3 bucket web site hosting endpoint, which is taking care of the redirect to the domain name without the `www` prefix.

The S3 website endpoints [do not support HTTPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff), so this works for http only.

Your solution is to create a second CloudFront distribution -- you need an additional one, because the second one has a different origin.  Configure this distribution with your SSL certificate, configured to expect the www hostname as an alternative name, and set its origin to the www bucket -- however, when you are setting up this second CloudFront distribution, [do not select the name of your bucket from the list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-create-cfdist.html).  Instead, enter the website endpoint hostname -- `www.migranthire.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.  Set the origin protocol to HTTP only (CloudFront has to send the request to the bucket as HTTP even if the viewer protocol is HTTPS.  You still get a green lock.)

Then, configure Route 53 to send www requests to the new CloudFront distribution, instead of directly to the bucket.  CloudFront will speak SSL, sent the request to S3, which will return the redirect, as it is doing now.

Comment: Hi there, how do you set the origin protocol to HTTP only? I have the same problem, redirects from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` don't work. Although I have created a separate bucket and CloudFront distribution for bare domain.

Comment: @jupiteror, go to the Origins tab, select the origin server, choose Edit, and look for "Origin Protocol Policy."

Comment: There is no such settings any more. Anyway thank you very much for your reply. The problem has already been solved.

Comment: @jupiteror if you don't see that setting then it is automatically set based in the fact that an S3 hostname was detected.  I actually stepped through a CloudFront distribution in the console in order to give you that information, but was looking at a distro with a custom origin instead of S3.